# Binding RichEditBox to .rtf files

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, azure-blob-storage, uwp-xaml

This is the object that I am dealing with:

```
class TopNews
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageURI { get; set; }
    public string BodyUri { get; set; }
}
```

The `BodyURI` is going to be a string with the address for an Azure Blob that holds a .rtf file, for example: `https://richeditbox.blob.core.windows.net/testformat.rtf` is a possible string to be on `BodyURI`.

This is my XAML layout so far:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image />
                    <RichEditBox TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                 IsReadOnly="True" 
                                 IsColorFontEnabled="True"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

It is missing a lot, but what I want to do is to bind the contents of that .rtf file up in Azure Blob Storage to my `RichEditBox` control in my XAML layout.

Now, so far all of the research that I have done on this has showed me that there must be some process in between, of course.

1. I must set up a download for the blob:

   ```
   Uri bloburi = new Uri("https://richeditbox.blob.core.windows.net/testformat.rtf");
   CloudBlockBlob cBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(bloburi);
   ```
2. I also found out how to load the contents of that .rtf file on a RichTextBox:

   ```
   richEditBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, await cBlob.DownloadTextAsync());
   ```

How can I do this? I was thinking that I can create a new class, like this one:

```
class TopNewsProcessed
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageURI { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public RichEditBox Body { get; set; }
}
```

So that I can run the process of download of the .rtf file and then just set it in the `RichEditBox`, but I have no clue how to approach binding this to the `RichEditBox` on my XAML layout. Is this a good idea? If so then how do I bind? Would I have to change the `Body` from `RichEditBox` to something else?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9a83d4e-26e9-476b-8818-7ccdf91a2341/richeditbox-mvvm-pattern?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So that I can run the process of download of the .rtf file and then just set it in the RichEditBox, but I have no clue how to approach binding this to the RichEditBox on my XAML layout

Creating an **attached property** is the right direction, based on the solution provided by BabaAndThePigman in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9a83d4e-26e9-476b-8818-7ccdf91a2341/richeditbox-mvvm-pattern?forum=winappswithcsharp)

I modified the attached property for your scenario:

```
public class RtfText
{
    public static string GetRichText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(RichTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRichText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RichTextProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RichText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RichText", typeof(string), typeof(RtfText), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, callback));

    private static async void callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var reb = (RichEditBox)d;
        Uri bloburi = new Uri((string)e.NewValue);
        CloudBlockBlob cBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(bloburi);
        var blobstr = await cBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
        reb.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, blobstr);
    }
}
```

For Model, you don't need to change, just keep the BodyUri string property.

View:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <RichEditBox local:RtfText.RichText="{Binding BodyUri}"
                                     TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                     IsColorFontEnabled="True"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Please notice that**, in your view, the RichEditBox's `IsReadOnly` property was set to "**true**", this will cause "**Access Denied**" exception at this line: `RichEditBox.Document.SetText(...)`

Please check my completed sample in [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/ListViewRichEditBoxApp1)

**Screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! This helped out a lot